# Pasar datos de una base de datos a otra distinta con tablas distintas (MySql)

Tags: mysql

Necesito pasar datos de una tabla de una base de datos a otra base de datos distinta. Además, en la nueva base de datos algunos campos no se llaman igual pero deben contener los mismos datos (por ejemplo en una tabla el campo para ciudades se llama "city" y en la otra "location", pero los datos que almacena son los mismos).

El esquema de las bases de datos es algo parecido a esto:

```
-basedatos1
--artist
---id
---artist_name
---short_desc
---location

-basedatos2
--artist
---id
---name
---short_description
---city
```

No es el esquema real, pero creo que sirve de ejemplo. Tampoco necesito pasar todos los campos, ya que la tabla nueva tiene campos adicionales que la antigua no tiene

Comment: Puedes mostrar el diseño de las tablas? y algun ejemplo ? así es muy amplio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al final lo he hecho de la siguiente forma:

```
INSERT INTO newDatabase.table1 (Column1, Column2) 
SELECT column1, column2 FROM oldDatabase.table1;
```

Gracias por las respuestas :)

Comment: Las tablas estaban en la misma instancia de mysql entonces, sólo estaban en distintos esquemas.

Answer (score 0):

Si no son muchas tablas te aconsejaría que hicieses la exportación a mano creando SQL's custom seleccionando los campos que coinciden con la estructura de la tabla de destino. Solo tendrías que tener en cuenta seleccionar las columnas poniendo los alias de los nombres de los campos la tabla de destino.

Es un poco laborioso pero creo que te servirá.